# Comparing values in a model cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4

excuse me , I m still new to **cakephp**.
What I want to make a custom function to compare between 2 values, but I want to send the values as parameters to the function.

here's my model :

```
<?php
     App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
    class PayGrade extends AppModel 
    {
   public $displayField = 'id';


public $validate = array(
    'id' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
        'uuid' => array(
            'rule' => array('uuid'),
        ),
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
        ),
    ),
    'Salary_max' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
    ),
    'Salary_min' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
    ),
    'Currency' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
    ),
    'eval_pts_from' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
    ),
    'eval_pts_to' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
    ),
);
    function compareVals($min,$max)
    {
        if($min >= $max)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
public $hasMany = array(
    'Jobs_levels' => array(
        'className' => 'Jobs_levels',
        'foreignKey' => 'Pay_grades_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

}

I want to compare (eval_pts_to with eval_pts_from) and (Salary_max with Salary_min).
I v searched but found some functions that calls the variables from inside of the function, which means I ll have to create 2 functions one for eval_points and the other for the salary

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not clear..when did you want this comparison?

Comment: I want to add it.. I dont know how

Comment: I shared a generic function to compare fields to validate here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21708996/1062304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code can explain You:

```
public function validationComparisonField($check, $other_field) {
    if ($this->data[$this->alias][$other_field] > $check[key($check)])) {
        return true; // passed
    }

    return false; // not passed
}
```

You can always get data from `$this->data`

Validation rules:

```
'Salary_max' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('validationComparisonField', 'salary_min'),
        ),
```

Comment: can you write how will I add it to these:

    'eval_pts_from' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'),),'notEmpty' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'),),),'eval_pts_to' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'),),'notEmpty' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'),),),
and these
'Salary_max' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'),),'notEmpty' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'),),),'Salary_min' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'),),'notEmpty' => array('rule' => array('notEmpty'),),),

Comment: You can return the result of `(comparison1 > comparison2)` directly; no need to wrap it in an `if ()` statement as it returns `true` or `false` itself.